# SwiftUI: NavigationBar title displayMode and appearance in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift

In SwiftUI, I set `.inline` display mode for `navigationBarTitle`.

I also use `UINavigationBarAppearance` and set background color.

But iOS 15 `navigationBar` is so weird.

I set `UINavigationBarAppearance` config in `AppDelegate`.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.beige
                    
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
```

iOS 14 is normal

[image]

iOS 15 `navigationBar` background color not change

[[image]

So I found solution for iOS 15 `navigationBar` background color.

Add `scrollEdgeAppearance` can solve it.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.beige
                
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

But it will have problem.

[image]

How do I solve the extra area and let it like iOS 14 version?

I also set `standardAppearance` for `scrollEdgeAppearance` but it not working.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.beige
            
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance
```

Comment: None of this is SwiftUI, you may want to remove your tag and edit the title

Answer (score 0):

I always achieve this by setting it in the init() of the content view

```
init() 
{
        let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        coloredAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(mainColor)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = coloredAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance
}
```